# Java ant script does not show warnings

Tags: java, ant, warnings, javac

I have a 1.4 java code and I want to compile it with a 1.5 compiler because I would like to see all warning messages. I added the -Xlint option to javac, but it seems there were no changes in the output, but I know there is at least a couple  of warnings in the code.

I added these two lines to my ant script's compile target tag:

```
<compilerarg value="-Xlint:all"/>
<compilerarg line="-Xmaxwarns 10000"/>
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used value and line attributes at the same time. Compilerarg requires "Exactly one of these", see docs. Try using only line, like: `<compilerarg line="-Xlint:all -Xmaxwarns 10000"/>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this isn't solved my problem. Still no warning messages appear in the output of compiling.

Comment: Ok, solved it. After I changed
    <compilerarg value="-Xlint:all"/>
    <compilerarg line="-Xmaxwarns 10000"/>
to
    <compilerarg line="-Xlint:all -Xmaxwarns 10000"/>
I've just forgotten to run a clean build.

Thanks for the help!