# How to display all java compiler warnings in ant script?

Tags: java, ant, teamcity

I have two fold questions,

1. Are all the warning displayed in Eclipse under Problems view from Java compiler?
2. If so, how can I list them with javac ant task? I have tried -Xlint:all and -Xmaxwarns 10000 as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213923/java-ant-script-does-not-show-warnings) but no luck, it just display some of them but not all I see in eclipse.

I need this to fail a build if warnings go up with TeamCity, if you have better and easier suggestions please share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it but you have to use eclipse compiler for this. Eclipse uses its own compiler, it is not regular `javac`. It is special because generates much more warnings than regular compiler and because can run code with compilation errors until you arrive in your flow to code that is not compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to display all the Java Compiler warnings in Ant:

```
<javac destdir="${main.destdir}"
    ...
    ...>
    <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
    <compilerarg value="-Xmaxwarns"/>
    <compilerarg value="9999"/>
</java>
```

Note you can't combine `<compilerarg value="xxx">` with `<compilerarg line="xxx">`, so I just use the `value` parameter.

If that doesn't work, what error do you get?

Comment: this doesn't display all warnings like unused imports.

Comment: You can change `<compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>` to `<compilerarg value="-Xlint:all"/>`. The first turns on all _recommended_ warnings. However, the documentation then states that _all warnings are recommended_ which leads me to believe that `-Xlint` and `-Xlint:all` are the same. I didn't see anything specific about this on the Java Compiler documentation. I saw a bug filed against this issue in [Bugtraq](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4963930), but no commitment to fix. Findbugs or PMD might be able to track that. Is there a javac option to show this?

Comment: You can use the [Eclipse Java compiler](http://owenou.com/2009/11/18/running-eclipse-java-compiler-with-ant.html) in Ant. That will point out unused imports, but I can't find a listing of the various command line options though.

Comment: Here is the command line arguments for Eclipse java compiler http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_batch_compiler.htm&cp=1_3_8_0

Comment: So, you can now use the `<compilerarg value="-warn..."/>` to your heart's content. I'll update my answer when I have more time.

Answer (score 0):

**Ant**:To see all compiler errors:

```
<javac debug="on" includeantruntime="false" .... >
       <compilerarg value="-Xlint:all" />
</javac>
```